# k8s tasks slowdown with no excess CPU or RAM usage

Tags: performance, kubernetes, containers, kvm, ceph

I have a small virtualised k8s cluster running on top of KVM on 2 physical machines. After deploying Ceph (a storage framework), all the k8s tasks like creating containers or starting containers became insufferably slow, like taking over a minute to get from creating to starting a container.

I checked the nodes for excess CPU or RAM usages, both work nodes and the master node is well below consuming half the assigned resources. I have about 10-20 pods running on each node at the moment.

I am not sure what to google and given my level of k8s knowledge am completely out of ideas. Anyone with similar experience or could point me in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: This is too general for anyone to really help. Look at all the performance data you have and then do something with it. Also why are you layering Kubernetes and KVM? That's fine for a learning lab but otherwise rarely used in practice.

Comment: I figured it's probably too general, sorry about that. As you probably noticed from my lack of understanding, this is indeed a learning lab. What can I do to narrow it down? All the metrics seems to be focused on the containers' performance, I couldn't find anything useful about the performance for the orchestrator (there's a whole bunch of containers involved with the master node). And all the metrics for the underlying VM seems to be barely used at all.